# Database version control

Tags: mysql, wordpress, git

I have a situation in which i can't be the only one to encounter this, but i can't find any satisfying articles, answers or thoughts. I have a Wordpress website on which i want to end up with a situation where i can easily return to a previous version if something goes wrong.

I came up with an approach as outlined in [this article](https://deliciousbrains.com/install-wordpress-subdirectory-composer-git-submodule/). I would then add another submodule to the root folder which contains the database.

Git-wise i have a setup like this:

```
|
|-- .git (Main repository called 'root')
|
|-- webroot/
|      |
|      |-- wp-core/
|             |
|             |-- .git (submodule with Wordpress core)
|
|-- database/
|      |
|      |-- .git (submodule with database)
```

For each development iteration i would then follow these steps:

1. pull database copy from live to dev (local)
2. start developing (with possible database changes)
3. when developments are finished and ready for staging (testing), pull a copy from the live database without the `wp_options` table (so content tables only) and merge this one in the local one
4. Export merged, local, database to database repository
5. push database repository to bitbucket
6. pull database submodule in 'root' repository
7. push complete development iteration with database backup

For the database syncing i'm thinking about [WP Migrate Pro DB](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/), but a shell-script export might also be an option.

The advantage of this approach that i had in mind was that each *previous* commit contains a complete working code, so in case something breaks down i can revert without any hassle.

Somehow this approach feels wrong, especially the database part. In [this topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/241109/is-backing-up-a-mysql-database-in-git-a-good-idea) a pretty solid disadvantage of storing a database in Git is mentioned, but i can't come up with any better ideas.

Anybody any thoughts about this mess? :)

Comment: Oh how I'd love an answer for this too!

Comment: I know this was asked a year ago, do you still need help? Also, why are you wanting to do step 3? Wouldn't this overwrite your development changes?

Comment: I don't really need it anymore since i realised that a whole database with content under version control doesn't make much sence, but i assume i wanted to merge the updated database structure with the live structure